# Date back vs date back to

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, difference

I don’t know why they use this expression. 
It’s a text about “We Are the World” from an English textbook.

> They recorded a song called “We Are the World 25 for Haiti” to aid people who were suffering from the disaster. As the title of the song shows, its roots **date back** 25 years.

**Date back to** is often found but **date back** isn’t, it seems to me. I did look up the expression in a dictionary. I found a lot more examples of “date back to.” The language textbook should prefer more-often-used expressions. But here **date back** is used. So I think that means the writer must have felt that “date back” is more appropriate here in the context. But I don’t know why. I want to know native speakers’ opinions. Is there any difference between **date back** and **date back to**? Is there any preference?

I’m waiting for you to “lend a helping hand.”

Comment: Incidentally, it should be *its* ***roots date*** *back* or *its* ***root dates*** *back*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Date back to** is used when referring to **the point or period in time when some event occurred**. For example, "These pieces of artwork date back to the 18th century."

**Date back** (without to) is used when referring to **the duration of time that has passed since some event occurred**. For example, "These pieces of artwork date back 3 centuries."